# error reading .. node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector/InspectorInterfaces.cpp'

Tags: xcode, react-native

has anyone had this error

when I run the project through the terminal it works .. however in xcode10 this error appears

app clang error

error reading .. node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector/InspectorInterfaces.cpp'

Comment: After upgrading to Catalina and Xcode 11.4 beta, I'm getting this error on virtually every project. It's confounding and as a student with deadlines, I just can't continue operating this way. I've run chflags and chmod and ls -l to double check permissions after mount -uw / from the recovery reboot all to no avail. Permissions are fine (have read, write, and excecute permission). I think this beta version or security/privacy on new build Catalina doesn't like non-local directories (I had all my stuff on a flash/thumb drive) because after testing a new project saved on the local drive, the prob

Answer (score 5):

Try giving XCode full disk access.

- Open System & Preferences
- Open Security & Privacy
- Switch to Privacy tab
- Select Full Disk Access Option from the list on the left side
- Click on the lock below and enter your user password to make changes
- Click on +(plus) Icon and then select XCode
- Restart XCode and Rebuild project

You will now be able to build and run your project.